# I cannot open my phpmyadmin in xampp.It shows access denied

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

it shows the following errors :-

```
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A socket operation was attempted 
to an unreachable host.

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A socket operation was attempted 
to an unreachable host. 

 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the network was not connected or not configured correctly. It is definitely an error on the client machine, not your server.

There isn't much you can do to "solve" the problem. Pretty much all you can do is upgrade the client's network drivers and check for connection problems (maybe they're barely within wireless range, or the Ethernet cable is missing its locking tab).